# Opening a div 'popup' from clicking a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, popup

When clicking the 'test' div, it opens up the div price-list-test in a popup way like this:

[image]

However, I am stuck on trying to get the div to pop up on the 'right' alignment of the element rather than left, like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var leftpos = $(this).offset() - window.screen.width;
      $(this).children().css("left", leftpos.left);
      $(this).children().css("display", "block");
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.price-list-test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  Open
  <div class="price-list-test">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more code like the page structure and the sections which are adjacent to this `.test` div... And also the code(HTML/CSS) of the element to which you want to align the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Make 'test' class position relative, after that set 'price-list-test' left : 0%

```
.test { 
  postion: relative; 
}
.price-list-test {
  left: 0 %;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```